# calculating log odds of unemployment rate

Tags: data-transformation, odds

Noob here trying to make sense of log odds calculation. I am trying to do some transformation on unemployment rate data. I read one paper that suggested performing log odds and this is denoted by:

```
x(t)=log(u(t)/(1-u(t) ))
```

When i applied that transformation as is, I get negative unemployment values. Is that normal?

```
unemployment rate figures: 0.044, 0.041, etc. 
Transformed unempployment rate figures: -3.08, -3.1523
```

Comment: Because the unemployment rate is not a *probability*, there are no *odds* involved here. The transformation described is more accurately referred to as the *logit transform*. The purpose of the transform is precisely to map $(0,1)$ to the whole real line (including negative numbers).

Comment: @eermun The negative values are not *negative employment values" -- the logits of unemployment rates are negative; this is not any stranger than the fact that the logs of unemployment rates would all be negative. Note that any proportion less than $\frac12$ will yield a negative logit.

Comment: @Chris The unemployment rate is a proportion (at least notionally), and would estimate a probability (the probability that a randomly selected individual fitting the definition used in the denominator would be among those who fit the definition used in the numerator). As such, calling it log-odds seems to make sense (though I'd agree that in this situation that *logit transform* would generally suit these circumstances better)

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal.

The odds $\frac{p}{1-p}$ belong to the interval $(0,\infty)$.

On the interval $(0,1)$, $log(x)$ takes negative values.

Hence, the log odds can take negative values, as is it may be taking the log of numbers on the interval $(0,1)$

The more negative your log odds are, the closer the original odds are to $0$, ie. the probability $(1-p)$ is far greater than $p$ and thus is close to $1$.

Comment: Ah right! That makes sense. Thanks so much for clearing that up.

Comment: @user2641784 1. please [merge](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your two accounts -- [the one you posted the question from](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/167776/eermun) and [the one you posted this answer from](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/167778/user2641784).  2. Please don't add "thanks" as answers. When you gain sufficient [privileges](//stats.stackexchange.com/privileges) you can upvote answers you like, which is the Cross Validated way of saying thank you. If you're satisfied with an answer, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers